# How to adjust or remove grouped tableView Header size

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a grouped tableView and it has four sections , I would like to reduce the size of the header section in some section headers and I would like to remove the section header in other sections. I have tried solutions in most questions similar to mine but nothing works.

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            tableView.separatorStyle = .none
            tableView.clipsToBounds = true

            self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight =  UITableView.automaticDimension
            self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 200

            self.registerTableViewCells()

        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        (view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView)?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray

        if section == 0 {
            (view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView)?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        switch section {
        case 0:
            let headerView = self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "\(TestHeaderView.self)" ) as! TestHeaderView
            return headerView
        case 1, 2, 3 :
            return nil
        default:
            return nil
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        switch section {
        case 0, 1, 2:
            return nil
        case 3:
            return " some title"
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        switch section {
        case 0:
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        case 1:
            return CGFloat(10.0)
        case 2:
            return CGFloat(10.0)
        case 3:
            return CGFloat(43.0)
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 250
    }
```

I would like to have the tableView section headers to have specific heights as highlighted in **heightForHeaderInSection**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be setting the dataSource or tableView delegates (unless it is happening in some part of the code not shown).  These will be needed for this (and most dynamic tableview functions).

For headers/footers that won't change size it is reasonably straightforward to create the them - return the view you want to use from `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` and the height you want in `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)`.  Set these to nil and 0 respectively to hide a header.

A simple example that provides different size headers for section 0 & 2, no header for section 1, and hides all footers.  I've set the headers background colours to allow them to stand out, and not provided the other methods such as `cellForRowAt`.  Note the height is controlled by the height method, not the frame height.

```
class MyVC1: UIViewController {
   var mapa: MKMapView!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      title = "Dummy TableView"
      view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
      let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x:50, y:100, width: 300, height: 680), style: .grouped)
      view.addSubview(tableView)
      tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
      tableView.dataSource = self
      tableView.delegate = self
   }
}

//add dataSource and delegate support
extension MyVC1: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      5
   }

   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      3
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
      switch section {
      case 0:
         let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: tableView.frame.width - 20, height: 90))
         v.backgroundColor = .purple
         return v
      case 1: return nil
      case 2:
         let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: tableView.frame.width - 20, height: 20))
         v.backgroundColor = .magenta
         return v
      default: fatalError()
      }
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
      switch section {
      case 0: return CGFloat(60)
      case 1: return CGFloat(0)
      case 2: return CGFloat(100)
      default: fatalError()
      }
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
      nil
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
      0
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you added `UITableViewdelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` ?

or try this `self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 80`

Comment: yes I have that , what I want to do is reduce the size of the section header in grouped tableView

Comment: can you please try this delegate method heightForFooterInSection

Comment: what do you suggest I return in the delegate

Comment: that will be height too try that

Comment: no change updated my code in the question and tested the change , nothing changes

Comment: try to give only heightForHeaderInSection and viewForHeaderInSection methods only and remove other non required methods then try .. any change ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201322/discussion-between-jok3r-and-erent).